# Can't post iterated list of dictionaries to api endpoint, only first dictionary in list is sent

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, python-requests

I've created a short script that will pull data from an excel file, put that data into a dictionary and the end goal is to have each generated dictionary be posted to the API I'm using.  But no matter what I do I can only get the first entry in the excel sheet to be sent.  What am I missing here?

I've tried posting by index of body but it says anything higher than index 0 is out of range, except if I print based on index I can pull any of them and they clearly exist inside the body variable.  I also tried posting by the "employee" variable but it only posts the first set of data.

```
body = []

for r in range(1, worksheet.nrows):
    fname = worksheet.cell(r,0).value
    lname = worksheet.cell(r,1).value
    email = worksheet.cell(r,2).value
    username = worksheet.cell(r,3).value
    empid = int(worksheet.cell(r,4).value)
    employee = {
    "Username": username,
    "FirstName": fname,
    "LastName": lname,
    "Email": email,
    "EmployeeID": int(empid),
    "IsActive": "true"
    }
    body.append(employee)

    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api-endpoint.com')
    conn.request("POST", "/employee/?%s" % params, json.dumps(body), headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = json.dumps(response.read())
    conn.close()
```

I'm not sure what's happening here because if I print body I get a list of dictionaries each containing the correct employee data but when putting them in the post request I either get only the first employee being sent to the endpoint or none.

Edit: the API finally got back to me and the endpoint will not except a list of employees so the post request must be in the for loop.

My code now looks like this:

```
body = []

for r in range(1, worksheet.nrows):
    fname = worksheet.cell(r,0).value
    lname = worksheet.cell(r,1).value
    email = worksheet.cell(r,2).value
    username = worksheet.cell(r,3).value
    empid = int(worksheet.cell(r,4).value)
    employee = {
    "Username": username,
    "FirstName": fname,
    "LastName": lname,
    "Email": email,
    "EmployeeID": int(empid),
    "IsActive": "true"
    }
    body.append(employee)
    for i in body:
        conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('buddypunch.azure-api.net')
        conn.request("POST", "/employee/?%s" % params, json.dumps(employee), headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        data = json.dumps(response.read())
        conn.close()
```

I have 3 employees in my excel sheet but only 2 are posted. The ouput of body looks like this:

```
[{'Email': u'jim@email.com',
  'EmployeeID': 80110,
  'FirstName': u'Jim',
  'IsActive': 'true',
  'LastName': u'Halpert',
  'Username': u'JimH'},
 {'Email': u'don@email.com',
  'EmployeeID': 80111,
  'FirstName': u'Don',
  'IsActive': 'true',
  'LastName': u'Julio',
  'Username': u'DonJ'},
 {'Email': u'toolman@email.com',
  'EmployeeID': 80112,
  'FirstName': u'Tim',
  'IsActive': 'true',
  'LastName': u'Toolman',
  'Username': u'TimT'}]
```

So why is the loop only accessing and POSTing 2 of the 3?

Comment: I think that last part is not meant to be part of the for loop.

Comment: It didn't work so I was trying inside the for loop but I can only get any employee data set sent if I use the employee variable now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this code does work:

```
body = []

for r in range(1, worksheet.nrows):
    fname = worksheet.cell(r,0).value
    lname = worksheet.cell(r,1).value
    email = worksheet.cell(r,2).value
    username = worksheet.cell(r,3).value
    empid = int(worksheet.cell(r,4).value)
    employee = {
    "Username": username,
    "FirstName": fname,
    "LastName": lname,
    "Email": email,
    "EmployeeID": int(empid),
    "IsActive": "true"
    }
    body.append(employee)
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('buddypunch.azure-api.net')
    conn.request("POST", "/employee/?%s" % params, json.dumps(employee), headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = json.dumps(response.read())
    conn.close()
```

The issue was a lack of unique usernames. But I figured I'd leave it up for anyone that has a similar issue with an API not accepting lists.

Answer (score 1):

You are carrying out your post request within the for loop, move this outside of the loop so that it receives the fully populated list

Comment: With the post request outside of the for loop it doesn't send anything.  I can only get it to send anything if I use the employee variable which only sends one of the employee data sets.